# SQL Server runtime error transactions handling

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select *    
from nosuchtable
```

leaves a transaction open

```
Select 1/0
```

also leaves transaction open

```
Insert into tbl (intcolumn) 
values ('text')
```

This aborts and rolls back transaction

1st example is compile time error

2nd and 3rd example is the run time error

Question: SQL Server behaves differently in case of the run time errors, why so?

I know that setting `xact_abort` to on will abort all the 3 above transactions.